# Executing a linq query similar to Dictionary format using groupby to retrieve value from another list

Tags: c#, linq, many-to-many

I have table User and Items where there exists a many to many relationship in the table List(which contains UserId and ItemId). Now I am trying to retrieve for each item who are all its users.
The schema for the tables are

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Item
(
itemid int identity(1,1) not null,
Item_Name varchar(30) not null,
PRIMARY KEY (itemid)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.List
(
itemid int not null,
Userid varchar(11) not null,
);
```

User table also has the same schema as Item table but Userid is of type varchar(11).
The connection string's name is MyEntities

```
MyEntities obj = new MyEntities();
```

The linq query is of the format

```
var test1 = from p in obj.User
            from k in p.Item
            where p.Userid == Userid //retrieving the items for a particular user
            select itemRes { itemid = k.itemid };
IEnumerable<itemRes> itemret = test1.ToList();


var query = from p in obj.User
            from k in p.Item
            group p.Userid by itemret.Contains(k.itemid) into g// error1
            select new Result { fitemid = g.Key, fUserid = g.ToList() };
IEnumerable<Result>output = query.ToDictionary(fitemid, fUserid);//error2
```

The first query works perfectly while second query throws some compilation error
Here the errors arise as follows

Error1:IEnumerable does not contain a definition for 'Contains'

Error2:The name fitemid does not exist in current context, The name fUserid does not exist in current context

The class looks like this

```
public class Result
{
    public int fitemid { get; set; }
    public List<string> fUserid { get; set; }
}
```

I am new to linq concepts so I don't know if my syntax and definition are right or not. I wrote a the first query to retrieve a list of items. In the second query for each of the item in list, I am retrieving the users of each particular item.

Please help me in rectifying the query....

> Update1: I was wrong about converting the query to toDictionary format.@Gusman and @Alex pointed me in the right direction so I converted the second query as

```
 IEnumerable<Result> query = from p in obj.User
            from k in p.Item
            group p.Userid by itemret.Contains(k.itemid) into g// error1
            select new Result { fitemid = g.Key, fUserid = g.ToList() };
```

and the error2 is gone

> Update 2:To remove Error1, I did what @kwan245 said

```
MyEntities obj = new MyEntities();
var test1 = from p in obj.User
            from k in p.Item
            where p.Userid == Userid //retrieving the items for a particular >user
            select k.itemid ;
IEnumerable<int> itemret = test1.ToList();
```

and the second query as this

```
IEnumerable<Result> query = from p in obj.User
                            from k in p.Item
                            where itemret.Contains(k.itemid)
                            group p.Userid by k.itemid into g// new error
                            select new Result { fitemid = g.Key, fUserid = g.ToList() };
```

new error that popped up is : LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] ToList[String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

This might be due to the wrong syntax but what will be the right answer

Comment: do you have a "using System.Linq" at the begining of the file?

Comment: Yes of course, otherwise the first query won't be also working,right???

Comment: nope, it would work if the User class is an IQueriable. the Contains method is an extension to IEnumerable in System.Linq, if it does not exist it should be because the System.Linq namespace is not referenced...

Comment: The reference is present in the file

Comment: I'm not sure about error 1, but error 2 is because ToDictionary will return a Dictionary<int, List<string>>, not a IEnumerator<Result>.

Comment: Nonono, everything is wrong, give me 5 mintues to assimilate your code :D

Comment: Last line should be: var output = query.ToDictionary(ed => ed.fitemid, ed => ed.fUserid);

Comment: are you sure you want a dictionary<int, List<string>> instead of a List<Result>?

Comment: What I want is to store the userid for each itemid. So I take the item id as int and userid as list of strings(userid is actually varchar datatype in my table). And how will I store the values in List<Result>. By the way i changed the last line to that you put and error is gone

Comment: The list would be a list of Result, and Result already contains the fitemid and fuserid, another thing is if you want to access to the elements via it's key (fitemid).

Comment: About Error 1: `itemret.Contains()` expects an instance of `itemRes` to be passed as an argument. It looks like you're passing an integer instead of an itemRes object. Try using `itemret.Contains(k)`

Comment: @chomba Shouldn't the argument inside contain be something we are trying to validate against like a Id

Comment: There's an overload for Contains that takes a custom comparer. You could alternatively use `itemret.Any(o => o.Id == k.itemid)` for that. The thing is why do you want to group based on a boolean value? it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Please provide more details so that we can come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple errors in your code, like:

- You cannot `group by` a function invocation as you tried with `itemret.Contains(k.itemid)`.
- The `IEnumerator<Result> output` is not a dictionary, so you cannot assign the result of a call to `query.ToDictionary(...)` to it.
- Your `query` actually is typed to return an `IEnumerable<Result>` (see it's `select` statement). So why do you want to convert it to a dictionary?
- You cannot create a dictionary using the `ToDictionary` syntax you used. Its available overloads are, listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and all require lambda expressions to map the `key` and `value` properties to use from the given `IEnumerable<T>` input.

Also after your edit it is not quite clear to me how the relationships are between `List`, `User` and `Item`, because you have not provided their **class** declarations in your question. Also, it is unclear what `MyEntities` exactly is.

For now (until other information becomes available), I am going to assume the following: The `MyEntities` is your context containing the 'List`,`User`and`Item`collections, where the`List` collection represents the many-to-many mapping between users and items. You can then get your result in a single query

```
var result = 
    from pair in obj.List
    group pair by pair.itemid into g
    select new Result {
        fitemid = g.Key,
        fUserid = g.Select(x => x.Userid).ToList()
    };
```

If your `MyEntities` only contains the `User` and `Item` collections, I am assuming their class declarations are the following:

```
public class Item
{
    public int itemid { get; set; }
    public string Item_Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string userid { get; set; }
    public string User_Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Which would make your query:

```
var result = 
    from item in obj.Item
    select new Result {
        fitemid = item.itemid,
        fUserid = item.Users.Select(x => x.userid).ToList()
    };
```

Those are all the *speculative* options, I can come up with based on the current information in your question.

Comment: The obj I am using here is my entity connection object(refer to the edited code). Since they hava many-to-many relation, I have to use navigation to refer the tables. I am trying to find similar Users(i.e users who have items in common). So for a user I am finding all his items. Then for each of the item, I am finding the users of it, So I can develop my code to sort other users based on similarity to the current User

Comment: How to use groupby for only the keywords in the list??

Comment: @Amalpriya  Please add to your question (1) the declaration of the `User` class, (2) the declaration of the `Item` class (3) If there is a `DbSet<Item> Items` in your database context (4) What is the type of `MyEntities`.

Answer (score 1):

1) What version of Entity Framework that you used ? Contains is only supported after EF4.
2) use the functionary for ToDictionary method as shown at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

3) Try change the code to :

```
MyEntities obj = new MyEntities();
var test1 = from p in obj.User
            from k in p.Item
            where p.Userid == Userid //retrieving the items for a particular >user
            select k.itemid ;

IEnumerable<int> itemret = test1.ToList();
```

Assuming itemid is int

Comment: It looks like the issue is that you try to use IEnumerable<ItemRes>.Contains(int) ? instead of IEnumerable<int>.Contains(int) so my suggestion is to change to above

Comment: Looks like k.itemid is a string so change List<int> to List<string>